# How to pre-install a Python package into a OpenWRT custom image?

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller, openwrt, egg

I'm developing a router and need a Python module [snmp_passpersist](https://github.com/nagius/snmp_passpersist) to be pre-installed.

The original source is coded in python2, so I modified it as to adapt to python3, and need to pre-install into the product image.

I know how to install a Python module onto a running live environment by means of pip and a setup.py that come with original source, but now I'm in the buildroot env of OpenWRT.

I read through the [customizing package overview](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/helloworld/start) of OpenWRT, but it is for C language and binary executables.

It looks like that some more steps should be done with a Python module/package instead of a `cp` command, e.g. compiling *.py file into *.pyc, and making a egg file with a lot of package info, etc.

Maybe it works to copy simply the egg file into the target lib folder, but I worry about there will be no version information in the PIP environment.

I want to know the correct/formal way.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow an official python package from Openwrt

Add the include makefile for python

```
include ../pypi.mk
include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk
include ../python3-package.mk
```

There is some built-in command for the makefile, ex: `$(eval $(call Py3Package,python3-curl))`

Pre-built the python package and you can get this in a custom image

Ex: https://github.com/openwrt/packages/blob/openwrt-21.02/lang/python/python-curl/Makefile